# `addmultisigaddress` syntax for POST request

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, multi-signature

Copied the body part from https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/addmultisigaddress/ and replaced addresses with 2 new addresses (regtest):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:18333
Authorization: Basic YmFzZTY0dXNlcjpiYXNlNjRwYXNz
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 186

{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "addmultisigaddress", "params": [2, "[\"bcrt1qvtp07jfnk5wcslr6xjmntnkxchzt7j2rzswnqn\",\"bcrt1qzwpuwrykaacx7057tnafyrd4nnfecc602gptca\"]"]}
```

Error:

```
{
    "result": null,
    "error": {
        "code": -1,
        "message": "JSON value is not an array as expected"
    },
    "id": "curltest"
}
```

Comment: You don't need the backslashes. Those are to prevent the shell from interpreting the " characters, but you're not entering this in a shell.

Comment: If I remove those I get a different error:   `"code": -32700, "message": "Parse error"`

Comment: I suspect you're making yourself hard by trying to play shell yourself. JSON isn't very complicated: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Oh, I see. You also have the remove the unquoted ".

Comment: That resolved the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I was doing 2 things wrong:

1. backslash `\` is used in [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398646/why-is-a-single-backslash-shown-when-using-quotes)
2. Extra quotes had to be removed

Thanks Pieter Wuille for the help.

Below request works fine:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:18333
Authorization: Basic YmFzZTY0dXNlcjpiYXNlNjRwYXNz
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 180

{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "addmultisigaddress", "params": [2, ["bcrt1qvtp07jfnk5wcslr6xjmntnkxchzt7j2rzswnqn","bcrt1qzwpuwrykaacx7057tnafyrd4nnfecc602gptca"]]}
```

Response:

```
{
    "result": {
        "address": "bcrt1q5pza3z8vmt29xv2kyw9nvd30t0sgrfnzv55s6g9q22df4pkqp65qtuf0nn",
        "redeemScript": "5221024b72aac0b3a6dab576b344fa36384d39e95c0bc05f4e6ddf6567b581c50031712103e38d84ad58ddc696ee67e08ebec0df5931ce729fdd234acb50a2ed6785a9badc52ae",
        "descriptor": "wsh(multi(2,[7aabbdcc/0'/0'/16']024b72aac0b3a6dab576b344fa36384d39e95c0bc05f4e6ddf6567b581c5003171,[7aabbdcc/0'/0'/17']03e38d84ad58ddc696ee67e08ebec0df5931ce729fdd234acb50a2ed6785a9badc))#yg7pyr0r"
    },
    "error": null,
    "id": "curltest"
}
```